# Display which cells are highlighted on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I currently have few tables on a page that with cells that can be selected or deselected.

Is there a way to display which cells have been selected when the user clicks the submit button?

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/h18yr46a/9/

and my code is below.

Thank you.

```
jQuery('table').on('click', function (e) {
    var ourTable = jQuery(e.target).closest('table');
    var sCount = ourTable.find('.highlighted').length;
    console.log(ourTable, sCount, $(e.target).hasClass('highlighted'));

    if (sCount < 4 || $(e.target).hasClass('highlighted')) {
        $(e.target).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
  e.preventDefault();
});


jQuery('#gridinfo').on('click', function (e) {
    alert("info");

});

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="our_table1">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="our_table2">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>

<INPUT TYPE="submit" id="gridinfo" VALUE="grid info">
```

Comment: What do you mean display? Highlight? Display a text box indicating which had been selected with a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a many ways to do this, here is one:

```
jQuery('table').on('click', function (e) {
    var ourTable = jQuery(e.target).closest('table');
    var sCount = ourTable.find('.highlighted').length;
    console.log(ourTable, sCount, $(e.target).hasClass('highlighted'));

    if (sCount < 4 || $(e.target).hasClass('highlighted')) {
        $(e.target).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
  e.preventDefault();
});


jQuery('#gridinfo').on('click', function (e) {
    var selected = new String();
    jQuery('.highlighted').each(function() {
            selected += $(this).text();
        });
    alert("these cells have been selected: " + selected);

});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm4eet9r/)